# Filtro http Spring security + Java Web Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, jwt

estoy trabajando en una API con Spring Security y con JWT. El caso es que tengo este método funcionando en una clase que extiende de WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
// We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
// dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
// all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
// make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
// store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
// Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Este método hace que sea necesario el iniciar sesión para acceder a cualquier url  que no sea "/authenticate". Lo que necesito es que sea del revés, es decir el permitir todas las url excepto aquellas que yo decida. lo he intentado con este código pero no ha funcionado:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
    // dont authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().
    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    antMatchers("/v1/ONG/todas").authenticated().and().
    // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
    // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

He buscado el cómo se realizan estos filtros pero no he encontrado la documentación. Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @Jose esta claro lo que necesitas, por lo tanto la solución es que indiques los recursos que no quieres que sean accedidos, ejemplo.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()            
        .antMatchers("/authenticate","/v1/ONG/**")  //Indicamos los recurso al cual si podemos acceder sin tener que logearnos
            .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**") //Aqui ponemos esto para indicar que todos los recurso con excepción a los indicados anteriormente se bloquean y se necesita autenticación para ser accedidos.
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
        .and.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 }
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste con .ignoringAntMatchers() ?

La documentación dice lo siguiente, no me queda claro si es lo que necesitás:

> Allows specifying HttpServletRequest that should not use CSRF
>   Protection even if they match the
>   requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(RequestMatcher).
>
> The following will ensure CSRF protection ignores:
>
> Any GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS (this is the default) We also explicitly
>   state to ignore any request that starts with "/sockjs/"
>
> **http.csrf()**
>            **.ignoringAntMatchers("/sockjs/*")**
>            **.and()**

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.html#ignoringAntMatchers-java.lang.String...-

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo implementado esto en mi codigo (es muy similar). Espero que te sirva de guia. Utiliza antMatchers y hasRole para identificar el "Rol" del usuario que desea acceder al endpoint. antMatchers posee mas metodos que te pueden servir como por ejemplo `permitAll()` `denyAll()` `hasIpAddress()` entre otros. Espero haber ayudado.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors();
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/{\\d+}").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/list").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/list/api*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/user*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(corsFilterExample(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

}
```

Comment: Explicar tu código basándonos en [answer], ayudaria a hacerla mas entendible

Comment: editado, gracias.